# ServiceNow: JavaScript TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, reference, onchange, servicenow-client-scripts

I am writing an onChange Client Script in ServiceNow and having issues with a Javascript error on the front end client. I keep getting a TypeError: Cannot read property 'u_emp_name' of undefined. the variable seems to vary as at one point i was getting the u_pos_office undefined as well, however the data is pulling correctly and there are no performance impacts on my code functionality.

What could be causing the type error?

Script is below:

```
function onChange(control, oldValue, newValue, isLoading) {

    var billNum = g_form.getReference('u_billet',findBilletInfo);
    console.log('Emp Name: ' + billNum.u_emp_name);
    console.log('OFfice: ' + billNum.u_pos_office);
    console.log('Career Field: ' + billNum.u_pos_career_field);

   if (isLoading || newValue == '') {
      return;
   }

    if (oldValue != newValue){

        findBilletInfo(billNum);

    }

    function findBilletInfo(billNum){

        console.log('Bill Num' + billNum);
        console.log('encumbent' + billNum.u_emp_name);

        var empName = billNum.u_emp_name;
        var empNameStr = empName.toString();

        console.log(empName);
        console.log(empNameStr);

        g_form.setValue('u_organization_office',billNum.u_pos_office);
        g_form.setValue('u_encumbent',billNum.u_emp_name);
        g_form.setValue('u_old_career_field',billNum.u_pos_career_field);
        g_form.setValue('u_old_career_specialty',billNum.u_pos_career_specialty);   
        g_form.setValue('u_old_occupational_series',billNum.u_pos_series);
        g_form.setValue('u_old_grade',billNum.u_pos_grade);
        g_form.setValue('u_old_work_category',billNum.u_pos_category);
        g_form.setValue('u_old_job_title',billNum.u_pos_title);
        g_form.setValue('u_losing_rater',billNum.u_emp_rater_name);
        g_form.setValue('u_losing_reviewer',billNum.u_emp_reviewer_name);   

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you debug your code?

Comment: I am going to look into a solution now. I was aware of what was causing the error in my callback but didnt know about the asynchronous running. was very insightful, will let you know if i find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be an error here

```
var billNum = g_form.getReference('u_billet',findBilletInfo);
==> console.log('Emp Name: ' + billNum.u_emp_name);
```

In this case `billNum` is undefined since `getReference` is run asynchronously. See the [documentation for the function](https://developer.servicenow.com/app.do#!/api_doc?v=kingston&id=r_GlideFormGetReference_String_Function).

This means that it won't guarantee a return value immediately or at all. This is probably why you get a record sometimes and not others.

You can move these debug logs within your `findBilletInfo` callback to check the values

```
if (isLoading || newValue == '') {
  return;
}

var billNum = g_form.getReference('u_billet',findBilletInfo);

function findBilletInfo(billNum) {

    console.log('Bill Num' + billNum);
    console.log('encumbent' + billNum.u_emp_name);
    console.log('OFfice: ' + billNum.u_pos_office);
    console.log('Career Field: ' + billNum.u_pos_career_field);

    ...
}
```

If you debug in Firefox or Chrome, you should be able to just log the object to the console to explore the entire object at once.

```
function findBilletInfo(billNum) {

    console.log(billNum);

    ...
}
```

The output will look like something like this in the console and you can see all fields at once.

[image]